# Seed GUID creation from assembly version for WIX installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, guid

Is there any way I can seed the generation of a GUID based on a string in a WIX .wxs project file?

```
<Product Id="Seeded GUID from $(var.MajorVersion)$(var.MinorVersion)" 
       Name="PCMTec" 
       Language="1033" 
       Version="$(var.BuildVersion)" 
       Manufacturer="weeooowwwww" 
       UpgradeCode="This GUID never changes">
</Product>
```

The goal is so that when I change my program major/minor version (eg major.minor.built.revision) it creates a new GUID, however if only the built/revision numbers it does not.

I can do this manually, but its something I should be able to automate.

edit: Is there any issue if I massage a GUID like this?

"9AAADB83-ACF1-4DB8-BE8B-69C8061A$(var.GUIDInsert)"

Where in the case of version 0.35 GUIDInsert would equal "0035". The last 4 hex digits are part of the node ID (eg the random/unique part of the GUID) would this still conform to what a GUID should be ?

Eg the version number appended at the end
9AAADB83-ACF1-4DB8-BE8B-69C8061A**0035**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with doing this but it will fall short eventually once you have to roll over from 9999 to 0000. You may never reach this many releases of course but still something to consider. You can just change it to now be 5 digits, of course.

But I'm wondering why you want to do this in the first place. There shouldn't really even be a need to do this. This GUID is supposed to represent a "Product". If you are using different binaries (from a different build/revision) is the msi produced really the same as the one from an earlier build?

Is there some problem you are trying to solve that was caused by using an automatically generated GUID with `Product Id="*"`?